# $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ entire function and $f(z)=u(x)+iv(y)$ then $f$ is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I was going through my introduction to complex analysis homework, when I came across this exercise:

> If $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function of the form $f(z)=u(x)+iv(y)$, prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

I've got completely stuck on this one. I think it might be something to do with $f$ being analytical, but I'm not so sure, because I was sick and couldn't watch the class. ):

Any hints are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint : Write down the Cauchy-Riemann equations and see what pops out.

Comment: I had written them before and didn't see anything that would imply $f$ being a polynomial.

I have that $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}$ and that the other partials are $0$.

I must be missing something obvious. ):

Comment: You should think about what it means for a partial to be $0$.  Also, remember that $u$ only depends on $x$ and $v$ only depends on $y$.

Comment: I had completely overlooked that, thanks. I'll try again.

Comment: Now it became completely obvious! Thank you! (: