# Show that $f$ is a polynomial regarding a given question

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

This is in reference to this [$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ entire function and $f(z)=u(x)+iv(y)$ then $f$ is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64343/596656)

Since $f$ is entire it satisfies Cauchy Riemann so $u_x=v_y \&  0=u_y=v_x$

But how does that show $f$ is a polynomial?

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u_x$ and $v_y$ are functions only of $x$ and of $y$ respectively, so the only way they’re equal is if they are constants.

Comment: And a constant function as long as it is not zero is a polynomial.

Comment: @ErockBrox ??? $0$ is certainly a polynomial.